# What does it mean to say, default keys in map?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections), it says, *An `Object` has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map. However, this can be bypassed using `map = Object.create(null)`.*

I could not understanding the meaning of `map = Object.create(null)`.

1) What does it mean to set `map.__proto__` to `null`?

2) In the above paragraph, what does it mean to say, default keys of map?

3) How these default keys are related to `Object` having a prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above paragraph, what does it mean to say, default keys of map?

You can use an object as a string-to-value map. For example:

```
var map = {};
map["foo"] = "pizza";
map["year"] = 2001;
```

You probably expect the mapping to be initially empty. That is, for any `key` value, you expect the expression `map[key]` to return `undefined`, because you haven't set any values yet. However, with a normal object, `map["toString"]` has a value! This contradicts our expectation from the last sentence, where we expected *any* `map[key]` value to be `undefined`. This is what the docs mean by "default keys" -- some keys are already populated with values, even though you didn't set them.

> How these default keys are related to Object having a prototype?

This is because objects inherit some properties from `Object.prototype`. All objects (or *almost* all Objects) in JavaScript have a *prototype*. If you ask an object for a property, and the object doesn't have that property, then it will check if its prototype has the value instead. In the `toString` case, the new object we created with `map = {}` doesn't have a `toString` property of its own, but its prototype, `Object.prototype`, does have a property named `toString`. Therefore, when you ask an object instance for a property named `toString`, you get back the `toString` property from the prototype.

> What does it mean to set `map.__proto__` to `null`?

The solution here is to create an object that *doesn't have a prototype at all*. That is, an object whose prototype is `null`. We can do this with `Object.create(null)`.

In that case, when we do `map = Object.create(null)` and then ask for `map["toString"]` we really do get `undefined`, because the `null`-prototype `map` doesn't have a prototype to get an inherited `toString` property from.

Comment: I already understand your answers to first two questions. My question is, why this is explicitly told for Map instance? obj = {}; also has default keys. For example: toString()

Comment: @overexchange This doesn't have anything to do with how `Map` works, exactly. This was just about how to use an `Object` as a way to map strings to values, like `Map` can also do.

Answer (score 0):

```
map = Object.create(null).
```

means create an empty object which wouldn't even get properties from `Object.prototype`.

If you tried

`Object.getPrototypeOf(map);` it will return null.

Comment: I understand this point. But what is the significance of talking this point with `new Map()` instance